# Should a hook function's useEffect list the parameters as a dependency if they're state values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Say I have a hook function that provides a useEffect

```
export function useTokenCheckClock(authState: AuthState, timeout: number = 60) {
  const [lastCheckTime, updateLastCheckTime] = 
    useReducer(updatePerSecondReducer, Math.ceil(Date.now()/1000) * 1000);
  useEffect(()=>{
     ... do something ...
     return ()=> { ... do cleanup ... }
  }, [authState, timeout] // <-- trying to determine if I need this
}
```

And a component uses this function as:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(...);
  useTokenCheckClock(authState);
  ... some handler logic or useEffect that may alter authState ...
  return <>...</>
}
```

When the `authState` changes and triggers a render.  Would the following occur?

1. the `useEffect` hook cleanup function in `useTokenCheckClock` is called
2. then the `useEffect` hook in `useTokenCheckClock` is called again

Comment: Ok I did a more isolated one my previous experiment seems to be wrong.  It seems like I do have to pass the arguments state update or not to maek sure the useEffect cleans up correctly.

I'll update the OP so it's more Q&A

Answer (score 0):

It needs it otherwise the effects won't trigger when the parameters change.
This is demonstrated by the following Jest file

```
import { cleanup, fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, Text } from 'react-native';
afterEach(cleanup);
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers({ advanceTimers: true });
});

it("does not work with empty dep list", () => {
  const useEffectCallback = jest.fn();
  const useEffectCleanup = jest.fn();
  const rendered = jest.fn();
  function useMyHook(state: string, nonState: number) : number{

    const [ myState, setMyState ] = useState(Date.now());
    useEffect(()=>{
      useEffectCallback();
      setMyState(Date.now());
      return () => useEffectCleanup();
    }, [])
    return myState;
  }
  function MyComponent() {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = useState("AuthState.INITIAL");
    const lastCheckTime = useMyHook(authState, 10);
    rendered({authState, lastCheckTime});
    return <Pressable onPress={() => { setAuthState("AuthState.AUTHENTICATED") }} ><Text testID="lastCheckTime">{lastCheckTime}</Text></Pressable>
  }

  jest.setSystemTime(new Date("2025-01-01T20:00:00Z"));
  const {getByTestId, unmount} = render(<MyComponent />);
  expect(getByTestId("lastCheckTime")).toHaveTextContent("1735761600000")
  expect(useEffectCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  expect(useEffectCleanup).toBeCalledTimes(0)
  expect(rendered).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
  fireEvent.press(getByTestId("lastCheckTime"))
  // remains the same
  expect(getByTestId("lastCheckTime")).toHaveTextContent("1735761600000")
  expect(useEffectCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  expect(useEffectCleanup).toBeCalledTimes(0)
  // rendered still because of auth state change
  expect(rendered).toBeCalledTimes(2)
  unmount();
  expect(useEffectCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  expect(useEffectCleanup).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  expect(rendered).toBeCalledTimes(2)
})

it("works with dep list", () => {
  const useEffectCallback = jest.fn();
  const useEffectCleanup = jest.fn();
  const rendered = jest.fn();
  function useMyHook(state: string, nonState: number) : number{

    const [ myState, setMyState ] = useState(Date.now());
    useEffect(()=>{
      useEffectCallback();
      setMyState(Date.now());
      return () => useEffectCleanup();
    }, [state, nonState])
    return myState;
  }
  function MyComponent() {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = useState("AuthState.INITIAL");
    const lastCheckTime = useMyHook(authState, 10);
    rendered({authState, lastCheckTime});
    return <Pressable onPress={() => { setAuthState("AuthState.AUTHENTICATED") }} ><Text testID="lastCheckTime">{lastCheckTime}</Text></Pressable>
  }

  jest.setSystemTime(new Date("2025-01-01T20:00:00Z"));
  const {getByTestId, unmount} = render(<MyComponent />);
  expect(getByTestId("lastCheckTime")).toHaveTextContent("1735761600000")
  expect(useEffectCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  expect(useEffectCleanup).toBeCalledTimes(0)
  expect(rendered).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
  fireEvent.press(getByTestId("lastCheckTime"))
  expect(getByTestId("lastCheckTime")).toHaveTextContent("1735761601000")
  expect(useEffectCallback).toBeCalledTimes(2)
  expect(useEffectCleanup).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  // authenticated which then calls set state to trigger two renders
  expect(rendered).toBeCalledTimes(3)
  unmount();
  expect(useEffectCallback).toBeCalledTimes(2)
  expect(useEffectCleanup).toBeCalledTimes(2)
  expect(rendered).toBeCalledTimes(3)

})
```